# IOS 8 Location Services Not Working

Tags: ios8, core-location

Summary:
Previously running apps failed to run geode code and reverse geode code. The reverse geode code fails because the geode code fails to provide a location. I then swathed to Apple's own LocateMe example code and also enabled the Location Services under Privacy. I also enabled the "Allow Location Access" under Location services to Always, but this setting changes back to nothing by itself after running the Apple's LocateMe or my own app.

Steps to Reproduce:
It seems location services SDK to get location is broken. The software that was previously working on iPhone 5 stopped working after upgrade to IOS 8.
Step 1. Load example LocateMe Apple's example Core Location example project;
Step 2. Under system settings enable Location Services, and also change the app's "allow Location Services" to always.

The Get-Location fails and "always" setting is removed.

Expected Results:
Getting location and location updates.

Actual Results:
See above.

Version:
IOS 8.0.0 and 8.0.2

Notes:

Configuration:
iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 Plus

Adding this this not help either:
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

Comment: I have same problem before, here is the solution for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/26075203/1998979

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v) \
    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)



        if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8")) {
            CLLocationManager *manager = [[LocationManager sharedInstance] clLocationManager];
            [manager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            [manager startUpdatingLocation]; // or what ever location function you need.
        } else {
            // The usual way for iOS <= 7
            // (Do what you did before) 
        }
```

In addition to the above, you will have to add a string value for the key `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in your info.plist file. The value is the string that is presented in the Altert when iOS asks the user whether to grant access to locations for your app or not. 
For backward compatibility you may want to add the key `NSLocationUsageDescription` too.